# Ubuntu 16.04 trouble with USB HDD not showing up and no wlan0 interface

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

After removing windows 10 and installing elementary in its place alongside Ubuntu 16.04, I ran boot disk repair to get back into Ubuntu. Since then I don't see wifi networks, I get a weird message about cryptswap asking for a password, and any usb storage I plug in is unseen.

```
    ifconfig                                                                                ✔  2263  23:28:51 
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:1f:af:06:1c:1f  
          inet addr:192.168.1.67  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2602:306:cd46:cb60:e0ee:a1b6:fdf9:6f0/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::2a84:2d51:691e:7ea7/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2602:306:cd46:cb60:1d20:37d0:8ca2:4b28/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5125 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4595 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3206602 (3.2 MB)  TX bytes:968265 (968.2 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7e00000-f7e20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3334 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3334 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:224934 (224.9 KB)  TX bytes:224934 (224.9 KB)


iwconfig                                                                                ✔  2262  23:28:48 
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.
```

lsusb shows my 1TB hard drive at bus 4 device 2, but I see nothing in nautilus or gnome-disks

Comment: Update: I have no sound either. Using the volume hardware buttons makes the toast and volume indicators go up and down without changing the actual sound.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I stumbled upon the fix:

sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04

As per: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_-_Xenial_Xerus

Apparently some of my kernel images got tweaked.

After executing this command and rebooting, everything works like a charm again.